# Adding a related entity in EF Core 7.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update a `Book` in Entity Framework Core 7.0 with a database-first approach, which works fine, but now I'm trying to update the `Genres` associated and it's not saving to the database.

`GenresChecked` contains all the genres that have been selected and the context shows they have been added before the save.

I have tried adding it manually but the model has a list of genres not a separate `BookGenre` model.

You can see in the code/images below the Model and that I've attached the Genres, and all other changes to the `Book` save.

I'd rather not create a separate `BookGenre` model as the new EF Core should be able to save attached entity's with relationships.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Showing the Genres have been added]

[image: Book Model]

[image: The on Post Method]

The `Book` class:

```
public partial class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("(^^((?!(0))[0-9]{13})$)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid ISBN Number without spaces or dashes")]
    [Display(Name = "ISBN")]

    public string? Isbn { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    public int PubId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string? Synopsis { get; set; }
    public bool Available { get; set; }

    public int? SeriesId { get; set; }
    public double? SeriesNo { get; set; }
    public bool NonFiction { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Replacement Cost")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal ReplacementCost { get {return Cost+Cost*(decimal)0.15; } }
    public virtual Publisher Pub { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Bookseries? Series { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; } = new List<Author>();
    public virtual ICollection<Genre> Genres { get; set; } = new List<Genre>();
}
```

The code-behind the `Edit` page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using KBBookLibraray.Models;

namespace KBBookLibraray.Pages.Books
{
    public class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly KBBookLibraray.Models.BookLibraryContext _context;

        public EditModel(KBBookLibraray.Models.BookLibraryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Book Book { get; set; } = default!;
        [BindProperty]
        public IList<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public List<int> GenresChecked { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Books == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var book = await _context.Books.
                Include(b => b.Pub).
                Include(b => b.Series).
                Include(b => b.Authors).
                Include(b => b.Genres).
                FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Book = book;
            Genres = _context.Genres.ToList();
            var FullGenres = _context.Genres.ToList();

            foreach (var g in FullGenres)
            {
                if (book.Genres.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var g2 in book.Genres)
                    {
                        if (g == g2)
                        {
                            Genres.Remove(g);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewData["PubId"] = new SelectList(_context.Publishers, "Id", "Id");
            ViewData["SeriesId"] = new SelectList(_context.Bookseries, "Id", "Id");
            ViewData["Genre"] = new SelectList(_context.Genres, "Id", "Id");
            ViewData["Authors"] = new SelectList(_context.Authors, "Id", "Id");

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            foreach (int genreChecked in GenresChecked)
            {
                var item = _context.Genres.Where(s => s.Id == genreChecked).First();
                
                Book.Genres.Add(item);
            }

            _context.Attach(Book).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!BookExists(Book.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        private bool BookExists(int id)
        {
            return (_context.Books?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

The model inside the `DbContext`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_Book");
        entity.ToTable("BOOK");

        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        entity.Property(e => e.Cost).HasColumnType("decimal(6, 2)");
        entity.Property(e => e.Isbn)
            .HasMaxLength(13)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasColumnName("ISBN");
        entity.Property(e => e.PubId).HasColumnName("PubID");
        entity.Property(e => e.SeriesId).HasColumnName("SeriesID");
        entity.Property(e => e.Title).HasMaxLength(150);

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Pub).WithMany(p => p.Books)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PubId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_BookPublisher");

        entity.HasOne(d => d.Series).WithMany(p => p.Books)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SeriesId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Book_BookSeries");

        entity.HasMany(d => d.Authors).WithMany(p => p.Books)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "BookAuthor",
                r => r.HasOne<Author>().WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("AuthorId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_BookAuthor_Author"),
                l => l.HasOne<Book>().WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("BookId")
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_BookAuthor_Book"),
                j =>
                {
                    j.HasKey("BookId", "AuthorId").HasName("PK_BookAuthor");
                    j.ToTable("BOOK_AUTHOR");
                    j.IndexerProperty<int>("BookId").HasColumnName("BookID");
                    j.IndexerProperty<int>("AuthorId").HasColumnName("AuthorID");
                });

        entity.HasMany(d => d.Genres).WithMany(p => p.Books)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                "BookGenre",
                r => r.HasOne<Genre>().WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("GenreId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_BookGenre_Genre"),
                l => l.HasOne<Book>().WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("BookId")
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_BookGenre_Book"),
                j =>
                {
                    j.HasKey("BookId", "GenreId").HasName("PK_BookGenre");
                    j.ToTable("BOOK_GENRE");
                    j.IndexerProperty<int>("BookId").HasColumnName("BookID");
                    j.IndexerProperty<int>("GenreId").HasColumnName("GenreID");
                });
    });
```

The Razor front end

```
@page
@model KBBookLibraray.Pages.Books.EditModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Book</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Book.Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Isbn" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Isbn" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Isbn" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.PubId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Book.PubId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PubId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.PubId" class="text-danger"></span>
                <label asp-for="Book.Pub" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Pub.PubName" class="form-control" asp-items="Book.Pub.PubName" />
                <input asp-for="Book.Pub.PubLocation" class="form-control" asp-items="Book.Pub.PubLocation" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Synopsis" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Synopsis" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Synopsis" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Book.Available" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Book.Available)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.SeriesId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Book.SeriesId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.SeriesId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.SeriesId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.SeriesNo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.SeriesNo" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.SeriesNo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Book.NonFiction" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Book.NonFiction)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Cost" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Cost" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Cost" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            @foreach (var genre in Model.Book.Genres)
            {

                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="@genre.Id" name="GenresChecked" value="@genre.Id" checked /> @genre.GenreName
                   
                <br />
            }
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach (var genre in Model.Genres)
            {
                @genre.GenreName


                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="GenresChecked" value="@genre.Id" />
                <br />
            }
           

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="./Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: What is "it's not saving"? What do you expect, what do you observe, what have you tried?

Comment: I've updated the question, I expect that genres will be added but once savechanges run it does not save to the database.

Comment: Show your code as text, not screenshots. Show all relevant code. Is there anything in `GenresChecked`, what does `Book` contain, and so on. Read [mre].

Comment: I understand what you are asking. Hopefully someone has also tried doing this before and the additional detail helps.

Comment: You don't have to have done exactly the same in order to answer a question. I have done exactly what you're doing more than once though. Again: is there anything in `GenresChecked` when you debug your code?

Comment: Yes it has all the genres that have been selected.